# MongoDB find by matching two concatened fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that has firstName & lastName fields, I need to retrieve items that matches specific fullNames:

Is there an easy way to write a query that would check that:

```
firstName + " " + lastName IN ARRAY ()... ?
```

--- EDIT ---

The reason to concatenate is that I don't want bill jobs in the result (considering it exists) if I have [bill, steve] for firstNames & [gates, jobs] for lastname.

Thanks!

Comment: Your input is an array of firstNames and an array of lastNames? And you join them by position in the array? If yes, I'll update my answer, but this is *still* something you should be doing with your input, not in MongoDb.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just want:

```
db.myCollection.find({firstName:"bill",lastName:"gates"})
```

or is there a specific reason to actually concatenate?

Comment: The reason to concatenate is that I don't want bill jobs in the result (considering it exists) if i have [bill, steve] for firstNames & [gates, jobs] for lastname.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the concatenated fields as your input. If that's the case, you'd be much better off splitting your input data in whatever language you're using and passing the separate fields to MongoDB.

```
var names = "bill gates".split();
db.myCollection.find({firstName:names[0],lastName:names[1]});
```

This will also let MongoDB use an index if one is defined.

Comment: I do not have concatened fields as my input, updated the q to make it more clear.